# Outlook Search Folder: Search actual e-mail address, not Display Name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, search-folder

I need an Outlook Search Folder that finds e-mail by searching the sender or recipient's actual e-mail address. For example, if I want find all messages from senders in the domain **example.com**, I use the search criteria **From... @example.com**:

[image]

But the search only returns messages where `@example.com` appears in the sender's *Display Name* (e.g. From: *John Doe <john@example.com>*). If the name doesn't contain their e-mail address, the e-mail doesn't appear in the search results.

**How do I search for e-mails based on the actual To/From/CC e-mail address, even if the address is not present in the Display Name?**

---

What I've tried:

- I've reviewed all the available fields on the *Advanced* tab. I see the "From", "To", etc. fields but they work the same way.
- I found [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8/create-a-search-folder-filtered-on-an-email/d654fb1f-6784-4111-829a-bde3016227a0), which suggests searching the Subject field and message body...but that is very unreliable.
- Google....but there's a billion results telling me how to do what I'm already doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need an Outlook Search Folder that finds e-mail by searching the sender or recipient's actual e-mail address.

It's possible to configure a Search Folder to find email based on the Sender's actual e-mail address (see below).  However, it's *not* possible to expose the actual e-mail address for the To, Cc, or Bcc fields. An explanation of why can be found at the end of this answer.

### Configure Search Folder to Search on Sender's Actual E-mail Address

***Note:***  These instructions are written for Office 2013, but the solution should work for at least Outlook 2007 and later.

#### Step A: Add a Custom "Sender's Actual Address" Field to Outlook Using a Form

These steps create a custom form that adds a new field to Outlook with the sender's actual email address:

1. Save the following custom Outlook form configuration with the file name `FromEmailAddress.cfg`:

   ```
   [Description] 
   MessageClass=IPM.Note
   CLSID={00020D31-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
   DisplayName=From Email Address 
   Category=Standard 
   Subcategory=Form 
   Comment=This forms is used to expose a sender's actual email address.
   LargeIcon=notel.ico
   SmallIcon=notes.ico 
   VersionMajor=1
   VersionMinor=0
   Locale=enu 
   Hidden=1 
   Owner=Microsoft
   [Platforms]
   Platform2=NTx86
   Platform9=Chicago
   [Platform.NTx86]
   CPU=ix86
   OSVersion=WinNT3.5
   [Platform.Chicago]
   CPU=ix86
   OSVersion=Win95
   [Properties] 
   Property01=FromEmailAddress
   [Property.FromEmailAddress] 
   ;PropTag=PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 0x0C1F001E
   Type=30     ; 001E = 30 in decimal
   NmidInteger=0xc1f   ; 0C1F
   DisplayName=From E-mail Address 
   [Verbs] 
   Verb1=1 
   [Verb.1] 
   DisplayName=&Open 
   Code=0 
   Flags=0 
   Attribs=2 
   [Extensions] 
   Extensions1=1 
   [Extension.1] 
   Type=30 
   NmidPropset={00020D0C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
   NmidInteger=1 
   Value=1000000000000000
   ```
2. Copy the `FromEmailAddress.cfg` to your language-specific Microsoft Office's Forms folder, located at:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX\FORMS\<LanguageID>`

   - `<OfficeXX>` is the Office folder including the version number (e.g. `Office15` for Office 2013)
   - `<LanguageID>` is your 4-digit language ID (e.g. `1033` for English).

     **Note:**  Administrative rights are required to save files to this folder.
     **Note:**  Office may be installed in `C:\Program Files` if you have a 32-bit OS, or a 64-bit version of Office on a 64-bit OS.
3. In Outlook, on the *File* tab of the ribbon click **Options**.
4. Click **Advanced** in the left pane, then in the *Developers* group click **Custom Forms...**
   [image]
5. In the *Options* dialog, click **Manage Forms...**
6. In the *Forms Manager* dialog, click **Install...**
   [image]
7. Navigate to the folder where you saved the `FromEmailAddress.cfg` file, select it, then click **Open**.
8. Click **OK** on the *Form Properties* window that opens, then **Close**, followed by **OK** twice to close *Outlook Options*.

*Credit to this [slipstick.com article](https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/adding-extended-mapi-fields-to-outlook/#more) for information on how to expose a sender's actual e-mail address as a field*.

#### Step B: Use the Custom "From Email Address" Field in a Search Folder's Criteria

These steps leverage the newly created field as criteria for a Search Folder:

1. On the *Advanced* tab of the *Search Folder Criteria* dialog box, click the **Field** drop-down, then click **Forms...**
   [image]
2. In the left pane select **From Email Address**, click **Add ->** then **Close**.
   [image]
3. Click the **Field** drop-down again, point to **From Email Address** then click **From E-mail Address** on the fly-out menu.
   [image]
4. Specify the desired Condition and Value, then click **Add to List**, then **OK** to close the dialog.
   [image]

---

### The Actual To, Cc, and Bcc E-Mail Addresses Can't Be Used as Criteria for Search Folders...

A thorough search of Outlook's other pre-defined fields, the [MAPI fields available through Outlook's Object Model](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/), and a review of properties exposed by [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) reveals there are no fields that expose these e-mail addresses *as text*.  There is the [PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842196.aspx) property, but unfortunately this is an object that contains each recipient as a separate item.  Accessed natively (using the Custom Form method above) returns nothing.

#### ...With One Almost Useless Exception

Using the VBA from this [slipstick.com article](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/recipient-email-address-sent-items/) I was able to add a User Defined Field (UDF) to messages that contained a single string containing the recipient e-mail addresses in the format `john@example.com, jane@example.com`. However, when selecting a UDF in the Search Folder Advanced Criteria's Field list, only UDFs defined in the Inbox are available:

[image]

If messages with the custom fields populated exist in the Inbox, they are found by the Search Folder.  However, such messages located in other folders are not included in the results. Unless your Search Folder is only interested in the Inbox, this is rather useless.

Reasons why UDFs don't work in the criteria of a Search Folder are documented [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27831699/Can-Outlook-2010-display-user-defined-message-properties-in-the-Unread-Mail-folder.html), [here](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/139349/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/570feb56-b010-4506-bd2f-967ef0eb386e/need-search-folder-view-to-show-user-defined-properties?forum=vsto).

#### The Pre-Defined Fields Are Still the "Best" Solution

When it comes to the **To:**, **Cc:**, and **Bcc:** fields, it's still best to use the pre-defined fields in your Search Folder criteria and *hope* the actual e-mail address is part of the Display Name (which it often is).

Comment: If anyone finds a solution for exposing the actual e-mail address of the To:, Cc:, or Bcc: fields in such a way that they can be used as criteria for a Search Folder, I'd love to hear about it.  Many others would find it useful too.

Comment: Great tip, but be advised this is the email address of the Sender.  This isn't always the same as the From email address (I know, it's ridiculous).

Comment: @TastyWheat Can you give me an example of what you mean? Are you referring to the fact the sender's email address can be set to whatever the sender wishes? Or something else?

Comment: In a few cases I get emails with a Sender of jdoe@mailserver.com but the email is From noreply@someservice.com.  This is done because John Doe took an action on someservice.com that triggered the email, although he himself didn't compose and send the email.

Comment: @TastyWheat You are correct. The original question seeks to work with the Sender address, ignoring "From/Display name/Sent on Behalf of" information.

Comment: Doesn't work with "doesn't contain" (Outlook 2016)

Comment: Wow this is a terribly klunky solution for something Outlook should  do better natively.

Comment: OMFG still a terrible answer.  Outlook - be better!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do fancy searches using the To/From/Cc/Bcc fields in Search Folders without creating custom forms, but there is [a work around](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3936-outlook-search-folder-email-domain-name.html) for finding senders in a certain domain using the "Mail from specific people" option. (This also works for the "Mail from and to specific people" option.)

1. When creating a Search Folder, select **Mail from specific people** in the "New Search Folder" dialog. Then click the **Choose…** button

   [image: New Search Folder dialog]
2. In the **From ->** box, enter the domain(s) you want to search for in the format: `@domain.com`. You can include multiple domains by separating them with a semi-colon (`;`).

   [image: Select Names dialog]

Comment: This is the only one that works for me.  But it ONLY gets email from one or more domains, but does not handle TO a speicfic domain.   I have 50+ clients to manage and having a folder with all the TO and From would be so useful!  But apparantly I am the only person in the universe who has ever had this problem.  Microsoft certainly has never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that using Search Folders, sorry. As a workaround, you can use Filtered Views:

1. Create a new Outlook folder View (View ribbon tab).
2. Specify the Filter for the created View on SQL tab:
   `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D02001F" LIKE '%@example.com'`

The **0x5D02001F** property is a PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS MAPI property. You can also add more properties to check using AND/OR if needed.

**Alternative way (using User-Defined Fields)**

1. Open the Inbox and create the user-defined field:
   1.1. On the *View* ribbon tab click the *View Settings* button.
   1.2. On the *Advanced View Settings* window click the *Columns...* button.
   1.3. On the *Show Columns* window click the *New Column...* button.
   1.4. On the *New Column* window type the desired name (say, "Sender Email" without quotes) and leave *Type* and *Format* as *Text*.
   1.5. Click *OK*, *OK*, *OK* to confirm on all dialogs.
2. Copy the 0x5D02001F property to *Sender Email* property for all messages in your mailbox any way you like, by using VBA or third-party software. Here is the key part of VBA (if you're going to write a script to copy properties):

```vb
... ' for each objMailItem get the value of 0x5D02001F property
Set objProp = objMailItem.UserProperties.Add("Sender Email", 1, False)
objProp.Value = ... ' The value of 0x5D02001F property
```

3. Create a Custom Search Folder and specify the *Criteria* on the *Advanced* tab: *Field -> User-defined fields in Inbox -> Sender Email* contains @example.com.

That's pretty much of it. Works perfectly for the whole mailbox.

Comment: This only affects a single folder. I need to find email located throughout the mailbox.

Comment: No way, sorry. You can only create a view "for all folders in mailbox" and apply it, after that click on each folder to see the emails.

Comment: As an alternative, you can create a custom Outlook user property and copy sender's email address to this property for all your messages. After that you'll be able to use this user property in a Search Folder criteria.

Comment: Nope, tried that. UDFs straight up don't work in Search Folders (for criteria). So dumb.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight up don't work"?

Comment: Search Folders, unlike "real" folders, cannot have UDFs defined in them (see this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/570feb56-b010-4506-bd2f-967ef0eb386e/need-search-folder-view-to-show-user-defined-properties?forum=vsto)). In the Fields selection box you **do** have a *User-defined fields in Inbox* entry, and can select any UDFs defined in the Inbox, but you the Search Folder will only find matching messages if they're *in the Inbox*. I've found no way to access UDFs in other folders.

Comment: @Twisty, they work perfectly in my case for Search Folders across all mailbox. Just FYI: Outlook stores UDFs in the Store itself when creating them in Inbox. After that you can easily use this UDF in Search Folder to find across all mailbox. I'll update the answer shortly providing the details.

Comment: Intriguing. I'd like to know the steps you took to do this. Are you interested in sharing this (in chat)?

Comment: I just updated the answer to include the details.

Comment: Excellent, I'll try it out when I have an opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

User Worthwelle gave a nice answer on how to identify the sender's domain, so the real challenge is establishing a test for recipients' domain. While the `accepted` answer does create a method to do this, I would describe it as a bit complex and outside the understanding of most users.

### Workaround with Same Outcome Using Rules/Categories

To address the use-case scenario that was presented in this question, here is a way to conclusively and consistently have a search folder reference all emails where from/to/cc contain `@example.com` domain.

#### 1) Create Two Rules

These should be done in the Outlook Web interface by clicking **SETTINGS** and then **VIEW ALL OUTLOOK SETTINGS** and selecting **RULES**. See settings below but note that:

- We are tagging all messages where any recipient has that @example.com domain
- Second rule to mark if `sender` address contains @example.com
- It's import to `Run Rule Now` or go into outlook and do a search then tag. This will ensure all previous messages are properly tagged.
- Going forward all messages that are received that have this domain will get categorized with this tag.

[image]

#### 2) Create Search Folder Based on Tag

This should be pretty straight forward. Create a new search folder, then select the prompt for `Categorized Mail` in the `Organizing Mail` section. Then click `choose` and then select the respective tag that a rule was setup for in previous step (in this case exampleTag).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ultimately it seems strange that a Search Folder can't duplicate results that a search Bar can, but this gets it done for me.